# Designing a custom FFC in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, cables, ffc

I am designing a custom FFC in Eagle, and am not sure how to convey the necessary information in the gerbers.

It needs to be custom because it is an irregular shape, but the actual connections are not complex (9 conductors on one side, no vias). The only part I think that might need specification is that the pitch narrows from 0.5mm at the connection points to 0.25mm along the length.

I can put the information about the stiffener, thickness, and materials in documentation, but I am not sure how the conductors should be shown. Should it be modeled as a trace, or as a custom part? Or is it enough to just write it in the documentation?

Comment: Try asking the company who's going to make the FFC for you. After all, they're the ones who set the requirements.

Comment: Have you ever viewed a Gerber output using a Gerber viewer? Several on-line ones will help you see what the manufacturer might see.

Comment: In the end, you provide a Gerber with one layer designated to contain the stiffener position. narrowing traces at the tip is probably best tackled by making a custom footprint for the tip connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's on the same layer as the conductor of the FFC, so if it's on the top layer, then the pads will also need copper on the top layer. If there is additional plating, then that information can be conveyed on another layer on what should be plated or in the cad drawing that is given to the PCB manufacturer.

Talk to the manufacturer, I've had them want to have information in different layers or in the cad file so it's best to talk to them.